# How to Change Value of ' + some +' element in src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a src script like bellow

```
<script src='http://www.example.com/dosome/' + some +'/afsddfa'></script>
```

How to Replace '+ some +' with element 3, 4, 5, or other element using jquery

Comment: its `some` a JS variable?

Comment: since I don't believe that constitutes valid markup, you wont be able to use normal js DOM functions. If you have this as part of a js string, then you would need to use a regex, but I would avoid putting this in markup at all costs. If you insist on it, you might be able to use innerHTML, but that depends on the DOM parser correctly reading your suspicious HTML

Comment: If it is not Possible Please tell how to add element using other maethod

Comment: can you show how the original and the modified look?

Comment: <script src='http://www.example.com/dosome/some/asdsdaa'></script> in above src how to change "some" with other element

Comment: you understand that even if the `src` is changed the already loaded content will not be unloaded right?

Comment: how to load load src with javascript

Comment: @Rajendra That I have answered below. Just check it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider you are adding a dynamically located script to your website:

```
let src = 'http://www.example.com/dosome/' + some +'/afsddfa';
$('<script>').attr(
{
   src: src,
   type: 'text/javascript'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var some=5;
var scriptUrl='http://www.example.com/dosome/' + some +'/afsddfa';
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", scriptUrl);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

});
</script>
```

This script will include you javascript file dynamically at run-time.

That script will start being downloaded immediately after this line `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);` is executed, and as soon as it's downloaded it'll execute or otherwise be usable.

Comment: Here you can add javascript file into head of the html by specifying the url. Make sure there is a head element. If not, adding to body works too. Is this is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the src with jQuery like this:

```
$("script").each(function(){
    var element = "/3" //added a slash so it doesnt replace other string
    var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
    var new_src = old_src.replace("/some", element);
    $(this).attr('src', new_src);
});
```

of course this is for all scripts in your page, you are not specifying more info in your question explaining what you are trying to accomplish, also this will not unload the already loaded script, a server-side solution would be better.

Here a version loading the new script src:

```
$("script").each(function(){
    var element = "/3" //added a slash so it doesnt replace other string
    var old_src = $(this).attr('src');
    var new_src = old_src.replace("/some", element);

     //load the new script
    $.getScript(new_src);

    $(this).attr('src', new_src);
});
```

using [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) you can load the new script and execute the content

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var some = 5;
var script = '<script src="https://www.example.com/dosome/' + some + '/asdfsaf.js"><\/script>';
document.write(script);
</script>
```

This script works well and I am able to change element.